# How to start ranging without UUID using estimote beacon android?

Tags: android, uuid, estimote, android-ibeacon

I am making an android application on beacon in this app I want to find estimote beacon. So I want to know that how to start ranging beacon without uuid and how to search estimote beacon. I want to find uuid of Estimote. If anybody knows please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Estimote beacons share the same proximity UUID unless changed. If you use [Estimote Android SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK), then default proximity UUID is declared in `com.estimote.sdk.utils.EstimoteBeacons.ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID` (`B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D`).

Using Estimote Android SDK you can start ranging without knowing proximity UUID. See [Demos from SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/Demos) (in particlar [ListBeaconsActivity](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/blob/master/Demos/src/main/java/com/estimote/examples/demos/ListBeaconsActivity.java)) and note that you can declare region as follows:

```
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);
```

Comment: I want to know one more thing that, how to calculate distance between user and beacon?

Comment: See Utils#computeAccuracy in Estimote SDK: http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Utils.html#computeAccuracy(com.estimote.sdk.Beacon)

Comment: i am having 3 estimote beacon and i want to add those beacons in arraylist but when i start ranging its repeating all the 3 beacons and adding them into arraylist and i want to do ranging in background.