# Ionic 2 How to search Estimote Beacons dinamically

Tags: ionic-framework, beacon, estimote

I'm working in an hibrid app (has to work in Android and iOS platforms) using Ionic v2. My question is ¿How can I search for all the beacons dynamically without creating a region of beacons?
Because, in all the examples that I have seen (e.g [How to scan all nearby ibeacons using coordova based Hybrid application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580410/how-to-scan-all-nearby-ibeacons-using-coordova-based-hybrid-application)) the developer define a region of beacons. The problem is that if I define a region of beacons in my code, the application always is going to read the same UUID, but I need that the application read a dynamic UUID because the Estimote Beacons are going to be placed in differents stores.
I want to know how to start ranging Estimotes beacons so I can find the UUID of the near Estimotes.

In this example ([How to start ranging without UUID using estimote beacon android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842466/how-to-start-ranging-without-uuid-using-estimote-beacon-android)) **Kamlesh** use Android Native, and I need to use Ionic Framework.

If anyone could help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Are you targeting Android only?  I ask because on iOS it simply is not possible to detect all iBeacons regardless  of identifier.  You must know at least the first identifier.

Comment: No, I need that the app also works with iOS. Do you any workaround o something that could help me with tha situation? Or, do you know it is posible to configure all Beacons with the same UUID? And then use Minor and Mayor values to difference each Beacon.

Comment: Yes, the closest solution for iOS is to configure all beacons with the same ProximityUUID, then in your Ionic 2 app construct you region specifying only the ProximityUUID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @davidgyoung I really appreciate it. I will do it that way, when I finish the project I will share the code in github in case anyone need it.